# Need help fault finding a custom PCB

Tags: avr, atmega, atmega328p, load-cell

I am designing a custom circuit board for a CG scale test instrument to find the centre of gravity for model airplanes. My design is based on the model here: https://github.com/olkal/CG_scale and it uses the same circuit except that my one uses an I2C display and has a regulator and lithium charge module and the ATmega328p chip is built into the board.

The problem is, when I power the board with the I2C screen plugged in, nothing happens but if I unplug the screen, D2 lights up. (board design files and schemas attached [here](https://github.com/Smartich0ke/CGscale-PCB)*) I have tried powering off a lithium battery and using the regulator I put in the design.

I was wondering if you could see something wrong that I couldn't. (Hopefully it's not something glaringly obvious :-) ) I hope I have given enough information but if I haven't, let me know so I can add extra details, images, etc.

*Edit: A PDF version of the schematic is now available in the github repo but you can open the full project with KiCad EDA.

Edit: I have tried flipping the LCD connector and it does not seem to be the problem.

Edit The display I'm using is an LCD 16x2 with an I2C adapter on it

Comment: It would be better to have .pdf format schematics rather than EDA files in some format that not everyone can read.

Comment: Indeed, there is even no mention or at least it is not immediately obvious which program should be used to open those files.

Comment: Okay, will export as pdf and say what EDA use. (KiCad)

Comment: What is the display you are using?

Comment: LCD 16X2 with I2C adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering if you could see something wrong that I couldn't. (Hopefully it's not something glaringly obvious :-) )

**Summary**: Yes, there are a few problems that I can see. You might find more as you fix these, or afterwards.

- Your current [20 April 2021 version of the schematic](https://github.com/Smartich0ke/CGscale-PCB/raw/53bb404938473b4a60c1ccdeee41a70e9e081f33/robotcontrol.pdf) shows an ATmega328P with 32 pins, so that looks like the TQFP package. Then it shows you supplying power on VCC pin 4 and AVCC on pin 18. That means you aren't powering all the required pins. You must also power the other VCC pin 6, for reliable operation.
- Similarly for GND, your schematic shows only GND on pin 3 being used. You must connect the other GND pins 5 and 21, for reliable operation.
- On the schematic, the only decoupling capacitors are for the voltage regulator - none shown for the MCU. That apparent lack of decoupling could also affect reliable operation.
- It seems that you have a power switch `SW1` that can connect `VCC` (5 V from a 7805) to `VCCIN` which is the battery voltage. Connecting 5 V to the LiPo battery is a **very** bad idea and could result in the battery overheating, rupturing or exploding, fire, personal injury, property damage etc.
- The charging circuit is also incorrect - details below.
- There are too many issues for me to provide images & fixes for all of them, but I have given some pointers at least.

**In short**: As you see, there are several problems. Instead of trying to debug it all in one go, I recommend you simplify & divide your work. For example (and there are many possible debugging approaches here): Get just the MCU running (e.g. a blink LED program), from a bench power supply, with the battery & charging circuit removed / disconnected. Cut related PCB traces if you have to, to disconnect the battery & charging circuit from the MCU. When the MCU on its own is reliable, then add the I2C display, and get that working reliably. Check and understand its power rails, its expected I2C voltage and any I2C pull-up resistors used on the display board. Then fix the errors with the charging circuit, and only when that charging IC and the STAT LED are tested & working correctly, connect that part of the system to the working MCU. (As I said, other approaches are possible - that is just one of them.)

---

Details of problems with the charging circuit:

Some problems can be seen in charging circuit on the current [20 April 2021 version of the schematic pdf file](https://github.com/Smartich0ke/CGscale-PCB/raw/53bb404938473b4a60c1ccdeee41a70e9e081f33/robotcontrol.pdf).

It shows the `STAT` output connected to the `VBAT` output. I have marked the problem here:

[image: annotated partial schematic showing charging circuit]

The block diagram in the [MCP73831 datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP73831-Family-Data-Sheet-DS20001984H.pdf) shows that `STAT` on the MCP73831 can be driven up to `VDD` i.e. about 5 V (to indicate "charge complete") - but on your schematic `STAT` is also connected to `VBAT` e.g. 3 V (dead battery) up to 4.2 V (fully charged battery). I don't know what will happen exactly, but excessive current could flow between the two voltage sources (`VDD` and `VBAT`), through the "upper" P-channel MOSFET on the `STAT` pin, when the device tries to drive `STAT` high. Conversely, when it tries to drive `STAT` low during charging, excessive current could flow through the "lower" N-channel MOSFET on the `STAT` pin. I would not be surprised if the MCP73831 device could be damaged by this error.

Also, the LED (`D2` in your schematic) is intended to be driven from `VDD`. Here is the schematic from the [MCP73831 datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP73831-Family-Data-Sheet-DS20001984H.pdf):

[image: "Typical Application" circuit from MCP73831 datasheet]

Comparing those two images, we also see there is a small decoupling capacitor missing at the `VDD` pin on your schematic (but you cannot exceed 10 uF, which is a limit for USB devices - stick with the 4.7 uF shown on the Microchip datasheet).

Comment: Thanks for a detailed and well written answer! I think the battery management circuit was the problem. The board design was never intended to use both the regulator and the battery at the same time so no explosions there! The EDA automatically tells me that there are multiple ground and VCC pins so they are all connected up and you are right about the need for decoupling caps on the MCU. They would've helped. I am thinking about redesigning the board. I will also do further testing on the current prototype.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have already answered the question yourself. Look closely at the pinout of the display and the pin out of the connector they maybe 'labelled' the same but the connector may be flipped.
That would be my first check.

Comment: Double-checked the orientation of the connector and tried plugging it in flipped. No luck.